# Using MATLAB to create a 2D array for external Thorlabs library

Tags: arrays, matlab, 2d

I am using MATLAB to control Thorlabs software. I am having trouble with any of the functions from the imported library that need to return arrays. Here is an example of my code I am using and the description from the manual: my code:

```
waveType=libpointer('int32Ptr',0)
pupil=libpointer('int32Ptr',1)
arraywavefront=zeros(spotsy.value,spotsx.value,'uint16');
calllib('WFS_64','WFS_CalcWavefront',hdl.value,waveType,pupil, arraywavefront);
```

I am pretty confident with the syntax for pupil and waveType because those parameters have worked in other functions but I am having trouble with the arraywavefront syntax. when I look at arraywavefront after calling this function, it is still a 2D array of all zeros. I have also tried:

```
array=zeros(spotsy.value,spotsx.value);
arraywavefront=libpointer('doublePtr',array)
```

which gives me the error:

> Error using calllib, Array must be numeric or logical

For context, here are the parameters from the library:

```
WFS_CalcWavefront(instrumenthandle, ViInt32 waveType, ViInt32 pupil, float arrayWavefront[]);
for the arrayWavefront parameter:
float[], this parameter returns a 2D array of float containing the data
```

would love any suggestions!

edit: the manual further states that the type for arraywavefront should be a singlePtr (equivalent to a float* in C), however whenever I try to cast arraywavefront as a singlePtr, MATLAB crashes